# Hashing passwords and signature with HMAC any security advantages?

Tags: security, hash, restful-authentication, sha256, hmac

I'm getting a bit confused about hashing passwords with a salt and the way of HMAC an password or using as a signature and so on. I've read a lot of articles about it but it seems that i don't got the point of using this or that.

I got this examples of using that ways (questions marked by a number):

### Hashed passwords

Password from user is hashed with SHA-256 and a unique salt for each user stored in the database. Password and salt is just concatenated like this `hash(key + password)` and run multiple rounds of hashing.

1. That may be vulnerable for an length extension attack right?
2. Would changing the order of values make any prevention of length
   extension attacks? So changing `hash(key + password)` to `hash(password + key)`?

A better way of hashing the user password seems to be HMAC. In this case using `hmac-sha256(password, salt)`.

3. But is this really better and more secure to use HMAC here?

Some people said it makes no sense to use a salt as a password for HMAC
    but the salt is not visible for the user because it is just stored
    in the database. For me it's nothing other than a password.

### API authentication/validation

For an API all users got a unique and random `api_key` and an `api_secret`.
The `api_key` is sent in all requests by an header to identify the user. That should be a kind of "stateless authentication".

The `api_secret` will be used in backend to generate a `signature` using `hmac-sha256((api_key + nonce), api_secret)`.

The `nonce` is a random value that is send in another header as plain text and as well as a hashed value to verify that the `nonce` itself won't be manipulated (well not really needed because it will change the whole `signature`)... so a kind of nonce-signature:

```
rand = random();
hash = hmac-sha256(rand, api_secret);
nonce = rand + "-" + hash;
```

4. But is this really more secure than just make something like `hash(api_key + nonce + api_secret)` and leave the `nonce` without any nonce-signature?
5. Is there any security issue by providing multiple HMAC-hashes at the same time that are hashed with the same `api_secret`?
6. Any other toughts about that in point of security?

*It's hard for me to understand what the more or less secure ways of creating a secure hash are. Some people said "ok, this is secure... you should do this" and then other people said "oh you forgot this or that attack or vulnerable". So i try to understand how and why in a simple and "i-am-a-dummie-way".*

Answer (score 1):

SHA-256 is not a great hashing method. Use bcrypt, PBKDF2, or scrypt.

Peppering (HMAC-ing passwords) is useful if you think you have the chance a SQL injection vulnerability down the road, and a lower chance of an application server vulnerability.

Correct peppering means your application server holds the key and it is **not stored in your database**.

If you accidentally have a SQL injection down the road, a hacker might steal all your peppered passwords, but wouldn't be able to steal the key

It sounds like you're going to be doing hashing on every request, which is going to painfully slow. You should hash once and provide a token

Comment: What is the advantage of using bcrypt instead of multi round SHA-256 hashing? Both should be slow isn't it? Use peppering and salting at the same time should be fine (database with salt and pepper in code). I'm hashing on every request to make possible bruteforce attacks slower. On a normal request there is no significant slowering.

Comment: "On a normal request there is no significant slowering" , ah but there should be. SHA256 is trivially crackable on a GPU and bcrypt not so much. You want the slowest hash you can find